# My flipclock goes too fast, and jumps over even numbers. How can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flipclock

My flipclock.js goes too fast and jumps over the even numbers.

I have experimented with the code, and it seems like something go wrong when i use the callbacks-function.

```
var clock = $('#clock3').FlipClock(new Date("April 10, 2019 18:37:00"), {
  clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
  countdown: true,
  callbacks: {
    stop: function () {
      $("#myButton3Show").hide();
      $("#myButton3Hide").show();
    }
  }
});
```

```
<div class="endgame2">
  <img src="Pictures/endgame.png">
     <div id="clock3"></div>
         <a href="https://www.myvue.com/film/avengers-endgame" target="_blank" id="myButton3Show">About Movie</a>
         <a href="https://www.myvue.com/film/avengers-endgame" target="_blank" id="myButton3Hide" style ="display: none">Buy Ticket on Vue</a>
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is to change the "About Movie"-button to "Book Ticket on Vue" when the countdown has reached 0 and the movie is out on the cinema.

It works, except that the clock goes too fast and jumps over the even numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is a [known bug](https://github.com/objectivehtml/FlipClock/issues/258) which should be fixed in the most recent versions.

You can try the following work-around if switching to a newer version is not possible:

```
var next_show = new Date('2019-04-10T00:00:00');
var diff = next_show.getTime() - new Date().getTime();

var showtime = Math.floor(diff/1000);
var clock = $('#clock3').FlipClock({
    clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
    countdown: true,
    callbacks: {
      stop: function () {
        $("#myButton3Show").hide();
        $("#myButton3Hide").show();
      }
    }
});

clock.setTime(showtime);
clock.start();
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply! I think I have the latest version? Must be the Beta 0.8.0. I replaced my min.js and css-file with the download from their website, and it is still not working. Before I make any changes to my existing code, is the 0.8.0 the latest version?

Comment: In that thread where the bug is first mentioned the final response from the author is "This should be fixed in the latest v1 draft on the js-es6 branch." So I guess that it might not have made it into the official releases yet.